# Ubuntu on dual 1440p monitors

Tags: dual-boot, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I am new to Ubuntu and have dual 1440p monitors. The scaling of apps on them is very small and also, Ubuntu is not running at 60 hz. Is there any fix to this? If I scale both the monitors down to 1080p each, then the scaling is perfect and frame rate is also 60hz. I have connected the dual monitors to HP Spectre, via the Thunderbolt port, if that matters.

Comment: You have both monitors running off a single port?  Perhaps the bandwidth is unsupported?  I suggest that you attempt more trial & error with different configurations and do more research to try to solve this issue on your own. At this point there's not much information to go on.  See if you can't obtain some more diagnostic information and perhaps come up with a hypothesis to test.  What options do you have under Display settings?

Comment: @Nmath When the resolution is set to 1440p, there is no option for refresh rate and when it's set to 1080p, then there is an option for refresh rate to be 60hz. Also enabling fractional scaling and setting it to 1.25 (at 1440p) will make the apps look normal and scale properly, but will not maintain 60 hz.

Comment: And no, they are running off of 2 individual thunderbolt ports

Comment: Based on your description I can't see any problem with the screen resolution if you think the scaling on 1080p is "perfect" and 1.25x scaling at 1440p is "normal" and "proper" --At 1:1 scaling at 1440p everything will be "smaller" than at 1080p.  That's not wrong or unusual in any way.  As far as the refresh rate, what is the observed refresh rate at 1440p?  Have you tried using a different cable or port?  All cables/ports/devices must explicitly support the resolution and refresh rate that you want to use.  Please try different configurations as a diagnostic step for process of elimination.